# Snort rule does not work when combining "content" fields

Tags: snort

I'm trying to write a snort rule which outputs an alert whenever a web server returns an HTML document containing a specific string.

I've come up with the following rule:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"Yay"; flow:to_client,established; content:"Content-Type: text/html"; http_header; content:"Hello there"; metadata:service http; sid:12345678; rev:1;)
```

The first `content` query checks whether the response contains an HTML document, the second one checks for the presence of the specific string I want to test the response against.

The strange thing is, when removing either of the `content` fields, the alert works fine. In combination, however, it does not.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: who's trolling? I found snort rule syntax that used the format I was suggesting. I guess the syntax I found didn't work ...

Comment: have you worked with `pcre`? It will be clunky, but it might work for you.

Comment: `pcre` should only be used if you're trying to match on a dynamic pattern, and should not be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but this has been something I've run into numerous times, so I figure that providing an answer may help others who have run into this.

#### My Explanation

In my experience, some versions of Snort have issues when switching from using HTTP options that reply on preprocessor parsing and then switching to not using them.  Given the rule you provided, the first content string:

```
content:"Content-Type: text/html"; http_header;
```

Utilizes the http preprocessor and the Snort engine sort of gets into the mode of parsing parts of the request/response.  Following up with the content string:

```
content:"Hello there";
```

... without specifying where to find it, the Snort engine has difficulty finding it.

Of course, this is my "theory" formed upon experience and trial-and-error troubleshooting.

#### Possible Solutions

1. Specify `content:"Hello there";` before the other content (move to the left).  If applicable, specify `fast_pattern:only;`.
2. Leave the `content:"Hello there";` where it is, but try adding the `pkt_data;` option prior to it.  This would tell Snort to forget about parsing HTTP request/response elements and move the doe_ptr to the beginning of the HTTP request (i.e. the packet) and then search for the content.  Or, if that content is expected in the file data of the response, use the `file_data;` option instead.  Again, `pkt_data;` or `file_data;` require you to put those options ***before*** the `content` options that need to be affected.